# About php regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have string like `{usr_lnk_@fname-lname.47_12}`.

where `@fname-lname.47` is username and `12` is user id, which is dynamic.
String may be like `{usr_lnk_@fname.lname_15}` and `{usr_lnk_@fname_160}`

And I want output like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/12">@fname-lname.47</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/15">@fname.lname</a>
```

Can anybody help me? I don't know about php regular expresssions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$string = preg_replace('~{[^@}]+(@[^}]+)_(\d+)}~',
                       '<a href="http://www.example.com/$2">$1</a>',
                       $string);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you fast and useful reply.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
preg_replace('/\{[^@]+(@[^_]+)_(\d+)\}/', 
             '<a href="http://www.example.com/$2">$1</a>', 
             '{usr_lnk_@fname-lname.47_12}');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(@[\w.-]+)/', $string, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```